# Logout from Office 365 with Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, office365

We got a public computer with windows 10 and the office365-suite in one of our meetings room at my company. On this computer people shall login into their company-accounts, so the office-software is licensed. Some of them don't logout when they leave. They just shutdown the computer. If a next user now starts one of the office programs, the last user will be logged in.

To prevent this, I'm trying to write an powershell script which deleted the cached credentials.

For Microsoft-Teams if found a script which works like a charm.

```
#Stop Teams process 
Get-Process -ProcessName Teams -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Stop-Process -Force 
Start-Sleep -Seconds 3
Write-Host "Teams Process Sucessfully Stopped" 

#Clear Team Cache
try{
Get-ChildItem -Path $env:APPDATA\"Microsoft\teams\blob_storage" | Remove-Item -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Get-ChildItem -Path $env:APPDATA\"Microsoft\teams\databases" | Remove-Item -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Get-ChildItem -Path $env:APPDATA\"Microsoft\teams\cache" | Remove-Item -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Get-ChildItem -Path $env:APPDATA\"Microsoft\teams\gpucache" | Remove-Item -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Get-ChildItem -Path $env:APPDATA\"Microsoft\teams\Indexeddb" | Remove-Item -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Get-ChildItem -Path $env:APPDATA\"Microsoft\teams\Local Storage" | Remove-Item -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Get-ChildItem -Path $env:APPDATA\"Microsoft\teams\tmp" | Remove-Item -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Write-Host "Teams Cache Cleaned" 
}catch{
echo $_ 
}

#Remove Credential from Credential manager
$credential = cmdkey /list | ForEach-Object{if($_ -like "*Target:*" -and $_ -like "*msteams*"){cmdkey /del:($_ -replace " ","" -replace "Target:","")}}

#Remove Reg.Key
$Regkeypath= "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Office\Teams" 
$value = (Get-ItemProperty $Regkeypath).HomeUserUpn -eq $null
If ($value -eq $False) 
{ 
  Remove-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Office\Teams" -Name "HomeUserUpn"
  Write-Host "The registry value Sucessfully removed" 
} 
Else { Write-Host "The registry value does not exist"}

#Get Desktop-config.json
$TeamsFolders = "$env:APPDATA\Microsoft\teams"
try{
    $SourceDesktopConfigFile = "$TeamsFolders\desktop-config.json"
    $desktopConfig = (Get-Content -Path $SourceDesktopConfigFile | ConvertFrom-Json)
}
catch{ Write-Host "Failed to open Desktop-config.json" }

#Overwrite the desktop-config.json
Write-Host "Modify desktop-Config.Json"
try{
    $desktopConfig.isLoggedOut = $true
    $desktopConfig.upnWindowUserUpn =""; #The email used to sign in
    $desktopConfig.userUpn ="";
    $desktopConfig.userOid ="";
    $desktopConfig.userTid = "";
    $desktopConfig.homeTenantId ="";
    $desktopConfig.webAccountId="";
    $desktopConfig | ConvertTo-Json -Compress | Set-Content -Path $SourceDesktopConfigFile -Force
}
catch{ Write-Host "Failed to overwrite desktop-config.json" }
Write-Host "Modify desktop-Config.Json - Finished"

#Delete the Cookies file. This is a fix for when the joining as anonymous, and prevents the last used guest name from being reused.
Get-ChildItem "$TeamsFolders\Cookies" | Remove-Item

#Lastly delete the storage.json, this corrects some error that MSTeams otherwise would have when logging in again.
Get-ChildItem "$TeamsFolders\storage.json" | Remove-Item


#Try to remove the Link School/Work account if there was one. It can be created if the first time you sign in, the user all
$LocalPackagesFolder ="$env:LOCALAPPDATA\Packages"
$AADBrokerFolder = Get-ChildItem -Path $LocalPackagesFolder -Recurse -Include "Microsoft.AAD.BrokerPlugin_*";
$AADBrokerFolder = $AADBrokerFolder[0];
Get-ChildItem "$AADBrokerFolder\AC\TokenBroker\Accounts" | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force
```

I already know that Office365 saves the credentials in these registry-keys
`Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\Identity`

But if I start some office-program again the auto-login just needs some more seconds.
So I'm asking for some other places, where office365 could cache/save the credentials.

Answer (score 0):

This script might help:

```
Import-Module MSOnline
$cred = Get-Credential
Connect-MsolService -Credential $cred
Connect-SPOService -Url <add you office365 SPO admin url here> -Credential $cred
# To get all enabled users
$users = Get-MsolUser -EnabledFilter EnabledOnly -All
# To get all the users
#$users = Get-MsolUser;
foreach ($user in $users) {
    Revoke-SPOUserSession -user $user.UserPrincipalName -Confirm:$false
}
```

A more sophisticated script can be found in the article
[Signout Microsoft Office Desktop Applications](https://quicklaunch.ucworkspace.com/support/solutions/articles/3000097824-signout-microsoft-office-desktop-applications).

Comment: I already when through your suggested article went through the code and tried it out on my PC. It changed nothing.